# how to save hex of memory at pointer location in variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory

suppose

```
char *  x = "aaa";
```

then  *x at hex ump = 61 61 61
i want to save this value to some variable to pass it to txt file
when i save it to var it change to "aaa" i want it to represent to HEX
i had tried this

```
std::string getmac_encrypted()
{
    // Load the necessary cipher
    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_256_cbc());

    // plaintext, ciphertext, recovered text
    std::string x = exec("wmic csproduct get uuid / format:list");
    std::string after = md5(x.substr(17, 30));
    // secure_string ptext = (secure_string)after;
    secure_string ctext, rtext;
    secure_string ptext = after.c_str();
    byte key[KEY_SIZE], iv[BLOCK_SIZE];
    //gen_params(key, iv);
    WriteString("12345678901234567890123456789012", 0, (char*)key);
    WriteString("1234567890123456", 0, (char*)iv);
    aes_encrypt(key, 0, ptext, ctext);
    
   // std::cout << ctext.size()-1 << endl;
   
    //aes_decrypt(key, iv, ptext, rtext);
    int* a = (int*)&ctext;
    DWORD WW = *(int*)a;

    // std::cout << WW;
    char* ppPack = new char[200];
   // std::stringstream stream;
    for (byte i = 0; i <= 48 ; i++)
    {
      
       WriteByte(ReadByte((const char*)WW, i), i, ppPack);
        
       // std::string result(stream.str());
        
       std::string wwww = ToString(ppPack, i, 48);
          
    }
```

any Help ?

Comment: like `std::ofstream ofs("out.txt"); ofs << std::hex << (int)'a':`?

Comment: 61 is the *value* of the `'a'` character expressed in hexadecimal. You just need to print those elements as integers, not as characters.